# A gui builder for wxPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

When i say a gui builder for wxPython, i mean like a drag and drop where i do not have to write the code out. Where it for example shows a button and i drag it on the screen and when i look back at the code it added a button in the code. or if i want to add a text editor it will add this code to the codeing:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import wx
  class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
      """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
      def __init__(self, parent, title):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
          self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
          self.Show(True)

  app = wx.App(False)
  frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')
  app.MainLoop(
```

Is there something like this for wxPython or just for python? Thank you

Comment: glade does that ... it creates xml files that describe the gui ... Ive found it much easier to just build your interfaces from scratch (like your example above) ... for wx at least you will only be able to find software that generates xrc files (the xml like files)

Comment: There are *lots* of GUI builders for Python -- enough that trying to agree on one would not be a pleasant debate. Personally, I tend to use glade/libglade.

Comment: wxformbuilder support different languages, including python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the two best known ones for wxPython are [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) and [wxFormbuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/). There is also [Boa Constructor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boa-constructor/), although it hasn't been updated in almost a year. I have also heard some people who like [DialogBlocks](http://www.dialogblocks.com/). wxPython also comes with something called XRCed (XRC Editor) that kind of works as a WYSIWYG editor.

Personally, I have found that designing wxPython code by hand is the easiest for me and it gives me a lot more control as well.

Comment: `Personally, I have found that designing wxPython code by hand is the easiest for me and it gives me a lot more control as well.` +1000

Answer (score -1):

You could always switch to PySide/PyQt4. It has a simpler API and Qt-Designer is one of the best drag and drop GUI designers I have heard about. I personally haven't used PySide/PyQt4,but from what I hear it is very well documented.

Comment: They do have a nice DnD WYSIWYG editor, but I didn't find the documentation to be any better than wxPython's. Both can be rather confusing at first.